# How do I migrate a VB6 ActiveX control to VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6, activex

I have a legacy VB6 ActiveX control used in IE to provide control of a parallel-port device from a browser application.  I wrote this thing about five years ago; It's a pretty simple control, and it doesn't require a lot of maintenance.  However, I've noticed that running the VB6 tools is becoming more and more painful over time, so I'm looking at the possibility of migrating this code to VB.net 2008.

This thing is super-simple.  It implements IObjectSafety and exposes a single public method, which we call using Javascript.  The control has no UI other than a single box with a caption that displays its name and version number-- useful for troubleshooting deployment issues.

How would I create the equivalent in .net?  Am I creating an applet?  Or a .net Assembly?  Any gotchas to look for as I try to make this transition?

(I should make it clear here that I'm not either a VB6 programmer or a .net developer-- I've dabbled in this stuff but it isn't my area of expertise, so go easy on me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called [embedded window user controls](http://www.google.com/search?q=embedded+.net+control&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) This link should get you started

http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=187

Note that the user will need the same version of the .NET framework installed as you use for compiling the project. This only work with Internet Explorer.